# How to hide system bottom navigation bar and show status bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying the following code:

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
  SystemUiOverlay.top,
]);
```

It shows what I want, but when I touch the screen the bottom bar appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears.

Comment: This is the default behavior, you can't change it.

Comment: Any guide? I'd like the system bottom nav bar to show for some seconds after a swipe up (as happens with SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky, but in immersiveSticky doesn't show top status bar)